# Calling isalpha Causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have the following program that causes a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("TEST");

    for (int k=0; k<(strlen(argv[1])); k++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(argv[1])) {
            printf("Enter only alphabets!");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've figured out that it is this line that is causing the problem

```
if (!isalpha(argv[1])) {
```

and replacing `argv[1]` with `argv[1][k]` solves the problem.

However, I find it rather curious that the program results in a segmentation fault without even printing `TEST`. I also expect the `isalpha` function to incorrectly check if the lower byte of the `char*` pointer to `argv[1]`, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I have code to check for the number of arguments but isn't shown here for brevity.

What's happening here?

Comment: Passing the wrong kind of argument to a function leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Don't do it. And a good compiler should warn you about it, listen ot the compiler, it knows these things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but it isn't that straightforward.

Comment: @rustyx Yup, that's part of the actual code, but I've removed the line here for simplicity.

Comment: As for your `"TEST"` output, output to `stdout` (which is what `printf` writes to) is by default *line buffered*. If you don't print a newline, the buffers won't be flushed. That's why you should always *end* your output with a newline.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed, printing with newline prints `TEST` before crashing. Thanks for this, but why is the segfault happening though?

Comment: `!isalpha(argv[1]` --> `!isalpha(argv[1][k]`as you pass the pointer casted to int instead of char

Comment: That's the *undefined* part of undefined behavior. It can cause a crash, it might seem to work, or something else entirely might happen. Once you have UB it's kind of pointless to discuss behavior.

Comment: @PeterJ_01, I know that solves the problem and have even indicated that in my post. I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: BTW: argv[1] can be NULL

Comment: I'm using `clang version 3.6.0` with this command `clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow test.c -lm -o test`

Comment: The code is a *constraint violation*. The compiler must emit a diagnostic and the behaviour of any executable is meaningless.

Comment: What compiler let this code through without errors/warnings?

Comment: @Lundin clang, apparently. I suppose it defines a macro that casts the argument (which I believe makes it non-conforming)

Comment: @M.M Yep... parameters passed to functions are treated just as during assignment, so it is indeed a constraint violation of simple assignment. I guess people shouldn't be using clang, then. gcc unconditionally gives a diagnostic message here, no matter if you leave out all warning options.

Comment: @Lundin I get no warning from various versions of gcc on godbolt either

Comment: @Lundin [I made a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565677/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general it is rather pointless to discuss why undefined behaviour leads to this result or the other.

But maybe it doesn't harm to try to understand why something happens even if it is outside the spec.

There are implementation of `isalpha` which use a simple array to lookup all possible `unsigned char` values. In that case the value passed as parameter is used as index into the array.
While a real character is limited to 8 bits, an integer is not.
The function takes an `int` as parameter. This is to allow entering `EOF` as well which does not fit into `unsigned char`.

If you pass an address like 0x7239482342 into your function this is far beyond the end of the said array and when the CPU tries to read the entry with that index it falls off the rim of the world. ;)

Calling `isalpha` with such an address is the place where the compiler should raise some warning about converting a pointer to an integer. Which you probably ignore...

The library **might** contain code that checks for valid parameters but it might also just rely on the user not passing things that shall not be passed.

Comment: The core issue is that the code is not valid C and the compiler ought to notify the programmer about this. So this is only "undefined behavior" because the produced executable is not C, but something else.

Answer (score 7):

1. `printf` was not flushed
2. the implicit conversion from pointer to integer *that ought to have generated at least compile-time diagnostics for constraint violation* produced a number that was out of range for  `isalpha`. `isalpha` being implemented as a look-up table means that your code accessed the table out of bounds, therefore undefined behaviour.
3. Why you *didn't* get diagnostics might be in one part because of *how* `isalpha` is implemented as a macro. On my computer with Glibc 2.27-3ubuntu1, `isalpha` is defined as

   ```
   # define isalpha(c)     __isctype((c), _ISalpha)
   # define __isctype(c, type) \
       ((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) type)
   ```

   the macro contains an unfortunate cast to `int` in it, which will silence your error!

---

One reason why I am posting this answer after so many others is that **you didn't fix the code**, it still suffers from undefined behaviour given extended characters and `char` being signed (which happens to be generally the case on x86-32 and x86-64).

The correct argument to give to `isalpha` is `(unsigned char)argv[1][k]`! [C11 7.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1):

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. **If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: All characters stored in a `char` are representable as an `unsigned char`, so that part seems overly pedantic to me. Sure, if you pass a negative value to isalpha (which is not EOF), it might halt and catch fire. But not if you pass a valid character from the minimum character set specified in 5.2.1.

Comment: @Lundin what do you mean?? So you're saying no one will ever write `äö` on the command line?

Comment: Converting the command line (or other) input to something safe is another story. Basically the same problem as `printf("Enter a number: "); int i; scanf("%d", &i);` after which the user types `A`.

Comment: @Lundin You're wrong. If `char` is signed, half of its values are not representable as an `unsigned char`. I keep rediscovering it approximately once or twice a year with MSVC compilers.

Comment: The cast to `int` in the macro seems unproductive; if they were going to use a cast for some reason they might as well have cast to `unsigned char`

Comment: @Joker_vD My point being: there exist no symbol tables with negative indices. Thus if you only use `char` for storing characters from symbol tables, you can never run into problems here.

Answer (score 3):

> I find it rather curious that the program results in a segmentation fault without even printing TEST

`printf` doesn't print instantly, but it writes to a temporal buffer. End your string with `\n` if you want to flush it to actual output.

> and replacing argv[1] with argv[1][k] solves the problem.

`isalpha` is intended to work with single characters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a conforming compiler must give you a diagnostic message here. It is not allowed to implicitly convert from a pointer to the `int` parameter that `isalpha` expects. (It is a violation of the rules of simple assignment, 6.5.16.1.)

As for why "TEST" isn't printed, it could simply be because stdout isn't flushed. You could try adding `fflush(stdout);` after printf and see if this solves the issue. Alternatively add a line feed `\n` at the end of the string.

Otherwise, the compiler is free to re-order the execution of code as long as there are no side effects. That is, it is allowed to execute the whole loop before the `printf("TEST");`, as long as it prints `TEST` before it potentially prints `"Enter only alphabets!"`. Such optimizations are probably not likely to happen here, but in other situations they can occur.

Comment: My answer contains the reason why *I* didn't get a diagnostics message.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Because your compiler lib is not conforming. 7.4 "The header <ctype.h> declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters." then 6.5.2.2/7 "If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype,
the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters" then 6.5.16.1, no case exists where the left argument is arithmetic type and the right argument is pointer type.

Comment: So, you should answer the [other question then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565677/wrong-argument-type-to-a-standard-library-function-defined-as-macro)