# Wrong argument type to a standard library function defined as macro

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Here is sample code:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    isalpha("X");
}
```

My question is: Is this code a constraint violation?  Equivalently, is an implementation non-conforming if it does not issue a diagnostic?

---

*Motivation:* Multiple major compilers don't warn for this code, even in conforming code. C11 6.5.2.2/2 covers that passing `char *` to a function with prototype expecting `int` is a constraint violation.

However it is not clear to me whether the provisions in 7.1.4 allowing a library function to be additionally defined as a macro supersede the requirement of 6.5.2.2/2. Footnote 187 suggests that the macro hides the prototype, but footnotes are non-normative.

The code `(isalpha)("X");` does give a diagnostic of course.

Comment: May I assume this is in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564810/calling-isalpha-causing-segmentation-fault)?

Comment: Reading this more carefully, then somewhat related in 7.1.4 we have "For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as a macro.185)" where 185 says "This means that an implementation shall provide an actual function for each library function, even if it also provides a macro for that function.". Again the foot note is not normative text. But I guess it would be interesting to try if `int (*ptr)(int) = isalpha;` compiles on the compilers that don't give a diagnostic message for the code in the question.

Comment: And if it compiles, then what happens if you do `int (*ptr)(int) = isalpha; ptr("X");`.

Comment: @Lundin That declaration would get the function obviously (function-like macros are not replaced when there is no argument list)

Comment: Yeah and if you get the function, you get the diagnostic abilities of detecting violation of simple assignment. My point here is, if a compiler still fails to produce a diagnostic through the function pointer version, it is definitely broken, as we can then ignore whatever 7.1.4 says. I'd do this test first of all, to check if a certain compiler is conforming or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key here is whether `isalpha` is allowed to be defined as a macro or not. C11 7.1.4 briefly mentions

> Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined in the header

although this chapter is mostly concerned with naming collisions and multi-threading issues etc. On the other hand, C11 7.4 says:

> The header  declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters.

and C11 7.4.1.2:

> `int isalpha(int c);`
>
> The **isalpha** function...

My take is that `isalpha` is to be regarded as a function. Or if implemented as a macro, some manner of type check must be ensured by the implementation.

Given that it is a function, it is pretty clear from there. For all functions, the rules for function call are specified in C11 6.5.2.2:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype,
>   the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the
>   corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version
>   of its declared type.

Note the "as if by assignment" part. This leads us to the rules for simple assignment C11 6.5.16.1, constraints. The code in the question would behind the lines be equivalent to an assignment expression such as `int c = (char[]){"X"};` where the left operand is an arithmetic type and the right operand is a pointer. No such case can be found anywhere in C11 6.5.16.1.

Therefore the code is a constraint violation of 6.5.16.1.

If a compiler lib chooses to implement `isalpha` as a macro and thereby loses the type check ability somehow by not performing the normal lvalue conversion of function parameters during assignment, then that library might very well be non-conforming, if the compiler fails to produce a diagnostic message.

Comment: Note that there's this "generally safe", for example that macros do not have sequence points...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Someone thought of that already. 7.1.4/3 "There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns." Making library functions a special case.

Comment: the footnote states that the intention of the "generally safe" is that macros do not have sequence points.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I suppose 7.1.4/3 might only apply _if_ implemented as a function. But unlike the foot note, it is normative text. And the only reason for that text that I can think of, is that some libraries may indeed implement some functions as macros.

Comment: Oh btw I guess the foot note could be about the sequence point after argument evaluation, before the function is called. That's a different sequence point.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation is that although the standard requires that there is an `isalpha` function, in 7.1.4 it specifically allows the implementation to additionally define a macro with the same name that hides the function declaration.

This means that calling `isalpha` in a program (without `#undef`'ing it first) is allowed to result in a macro expansion to something other than the literal function call for which 6.5.2.2 would require a diagnostic.